# Autopatch with EAR applicaton on jboss

Tags: jboss, ear, sql-update

Has anyone deployed autopatch (the database upgrade tool) in an ear application (on jboss server). Autopatch supports war kind of applications out of the box but for ear kind of applications it would need some extensions.
Moreover I am unable to provide the .sql files inside the ejb jar inside the ear as the location to look for patches to autopatch. Jboss 5 uses VFS and hence there is no reliable way to know the full URL to the jars.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing and how does this relate to liquibase?

Comment: does not relate to liquibase. have remoed the tag. Problem - patches of autopatch are within a jar within an ear on jbos..how do I make autopatch read those.